# How to handle data structures with indices larger than 32 bits?

Tags: c, search, indexing, data-structures, hashtable

I have a large index of size 80-bits and its corresponding data to be stored in a data structure on which I need to search. Can we use the 80-bit index in a hash table?? Or is there a better alternative data structure that will take a constant time for lookup (search)?

**EDIT:**

I think my question was not clear.... Here is the setup --- I have millions of files for which I will produce a cryptographic hash trapdoor of size 80-bits (to represent the file securely) and each 80-bit trapdoor is to be stored with its data in a data structure like hash table. Now since the domain of 80-bit trapdoor is larger than the range of hash table, there will be collisions for sure. But I need unique <80-bit trapdoor,data> pairs to be stored in the data structure. How can I achieve this using hash table? Or if there is any other alternative DS?

**EDIT 2 :**

Let's say that I created a hash table and there occurred a collision when adding the keys (say `x` & `y` in order) because the hash function generated the same index (`i`) for those keys. But by using collision resolution techniques (eg. double hashing), `y` is inserted in a different location `j` which is not `i`. I understand till this point. Now if I want to search based on a key y, does the hash table return the location i or j? If not `i`, how will it return `j` (the exact desired record)? does it store any counter(probe) for number of collisions?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably review [how hash tables work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

The object you want to use as an index are passed through an hash function and the the resulting value is used to find the memory position where you should place/look for the data associated to that index value.

If you need constant time lookups go for an hash table. Just be sure to use an appropriate hash function.

Comment: thanks for the reply.....I think my question was not clear.... Here is the setup --- I have millions of files for which i will produce a cryptographic hash trapdoor of size 80-bits (to represent the file securely) and each 80-bit trapdoor is to be stored with its data in a data structure like hash table. Now since the domain of 80-bit trapdoor is larger than the range of hash table, there will be collisions for sure. But I need unique <80-bit trapdoor,data> pairs to be stored in the data structure. How can I achieve this using hash table? Or if there is any other alternative DS?

Comment: Probably I still can't get what you are asking. Hash tables can [handle collisions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution) but I'm not sure it's what you're asking for.

Comment: Lets say that I created a hash table and there occurred a collision when adding the keys (say x & y in order) because the hash function generated the same index (i) for those keys. But by using collision resolution techniques (eg. double hashing), y is inserted in a different location j which is not i. I understand till this point. Now if I want to search based on a key y, does the hash table return the location i or j? If not i, how will it return j(the exact desired record)? does it store any counter(probe) for number of collisions?

Comment: Collision resolution works in two steps. Given a key `K` it first computes its hash `h(K)` and gets the corresponding location.
At this point it checks whether the key of the element stored at that location is equal to `K`. If it is it returns the corresponding value, otherwise it goes on computing the next location until it finds the desired key.

Note that, given the choice of an adequate hash function, the values should be spread evenly among all the buckets and thus it should still have an `O(1)` complexity.

Comment: so the point is the key should also be stored in the record, that means the record is composed of <key-value> pairs, right? correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Yes. Are you trying to implement your own hash table? I recommend you to take advantage of some already existing implementation unless you are willing to learn how the internals of an  hash table work

Comment: thank you for your suggestion.....the thing is i need to implement my project in C. So is there any existing implementation of hash table in C? And the 80-bit trapdoor i generate is using SHA256 cryptographic hash function, so if i truncate that 80-bit to 16-bit index, is it advisable to use that as an index of my hash table without using a redundant hash function and also to get uniformity that avoids collision to maximum extent?

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever you want as index in a hash table if you provide a hash function. I don't hink there is a better alternative if you want constant time access.